# Puppeteer Error no node found for selector (button click)

Tags: node.js, button, click, puppeteer, hidden

I try to click on button using Puppeteer.
Web page with button I need to click :

```html
<div class="submit_fields">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="iblock_submit" value="Y">
<input class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" onclick="gtag('event','Клик по кнопке из раздела', {'event_category': 'Передача показаний','event_label':'Передать показания'}); ym(57063811,'reachGoal','meter_reading_inner'); return true;" type="submit" name="iblock_submit" value="передать">
</div>
```

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
  'defaultViewport' : { 'width' : 1920, 'height' : 1080 }
});

  const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://gesbt.ru/chastnym-litsam/peredacha-pokazaniy/');

//code skipped(fill form, NO ERROR)

  await page.waitForSelector('#iblock_submit', { hidden: true}); //NO ERROR ONLY THIS ROW

  await page.click('#iblock_submit'); // GOT ERROR
```

**ERROR: No node found for selector: #iblock_submit**

Answer (score 2):

Based on the html in your question, there is no element with id `iblock_submit`, which is what you've typed in:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#iblock_submit', { hidden: true });
await page.click('#iblock_submit'); // GOT ERROR
```

If you want to find an element with `name="iblock_submit"`, you want to type e.g. this:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('[name="iblock_submit"]', { hidden: false });
await page.click('[name="iblock_submit"]');
```

**EDIT:**

You need to know what's going on on the website, try to experiment with it. Correct selectors are not the only thing you need to get right. Waiting for something to happen is another thing to consider:

```js
await page.goto('https://gesbt.ru/chastnym-litsam/peredacha-pokazaniy/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```

This might be a good practice, you can try it in your context and see if it helps. You can see all the options you can wait for in the documentation: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

Comment: I tried your code, I got new ERROR: 
"Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

Comment: @AndreyAndreev: you need to figure out what's going on on the website. Working with waits correctly might be what you're missing. I've edited my answer, so it might give you new ideas.

Comment: I tested it, the same error. Can I send you full code (with personal data) to check with web site?